# Samba AD user with same name as local user

Tags: user-accounts, samba, domain, active-directory

I just started using Samba as a domain controller at home. I have set up so that users who log on to the server have users and home folders created if it's the first time etc.

I have one issue though. I had a local user on the linux server with my common user name, let's call him **foo**. Once I made Samba a DC and started adding the computers to it I wanted to use my standard **foo** user name to log in to those.

This works fine. But the server get a bit confused at times since there happened to be a local user with that name first. So right now there is a **foo** user and a **DOMAIN\foo** user on the server.

What happens is that if I ssh to the server using my **DOMAIN\foo** user, it logs in fine, but the linux machine thinks I'm the local user **foo**. This confuses file permissions etc a bit.

So, I'm guessing I have to remove the local user **foo** somehow and only keep **DOMAIN\foo**. But I'm not sure how best to do that. The local user **foo** was my "main" user with wich I did all the *sudo* stuff needed etc.

So what is my best plan of action here?

Note that if we start to talk a lot of AD terms I'll probably get lost since I'm quite new to it.

Comment: How did you solve this? I have the same problem and I'm looking for the best solution.